# New material crash after GPU change

Tags: hardware

my workstation was upgraded with a better GPU, but now Blender just crashes if I create a new material, even on the startup scene. Is there some setting to edit after changing the GPU?

Comment: If you open Preferences and navigate to System (Edit > Preferences > System), do you see your graphics card listed under CUDA or OpenCL? If it isn't selected, select it and save settings. See attached image for reference. https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcxA2.png

Comment: The "new" GPU is a Quadro 600, still relatively old. It's not listed and displays "No compatible GPU found".

Comment: Have you re-installed the drivers? Also, if you open Help > System Information you can save a text file of the system as Blender sees it. In that file, look under 'OpenGL:'; this shows info about the detected GPU, if any are found at all.

Do you see anything listed there? If so, does that match the new GPU type, and what is the listed driver version?

Comment: I don't think you can use Quadro 600 for rendering. However that's not a huge loss - I had one of those when it was still supported and it used to render even slower than an old 4 core i7 2600K CPU. It support OpenGL 4.4 though so it should work. Maybe the crash is because of conflicting settings that still have the old GPU set. Maybe try temporarily renaming your user preference folder (`%appdata%\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.80` on Windows) or load factory settings and see if it fixes the issue. In any case this is a bug and should be reported.

Comment: I tried that, but it still crashes. The GPU is listed in the system info:

Comment: OpenGL:
============================================

renderer: 'Quadro 600/PCIe/SSE2'
vendor:  'NVIDIA Corporation'
version: '4.4.0'

Comment: You could try looking for older drivers. There might be a bug in the drivers and some version might work...

Comment: The most recent driver for the Quadro 600 on Windows 10 64 bit is 377.83. You can download the drivers from the official [Nvidia website](https://www.nvidia.de/Download/index.aspx?lang=en).